# Drawing Lines on android with matrix

Tags: java, android

Can a matrix be used when drawing lines and paths on android?

the DrawBitmap mathod takes a matrix as argument, I cannot find anything similar
when drawing lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Canvas drawBitmap method uses the matrix to transform the image as it is drawn.  See this URL for the details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap

(android.graphics.Bitmap, android.graphics.Matrix, android.graphics.Paint)

There are several drawLine methods on the Canvas object, but none take a matrix as a parameter.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine

(float, float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint)

Your best bet is to use one of the Canvas's rotate, skew, and translate methods.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: Does this allow me to rotate, skew and translate every separate bitmap too? I am currently able to draw and transform a full hierarchical tree of objects (containing a bitmap, position and rotation vectors). This means if I translate the parent (e.g. world object) every sub-object transforms with it accordingly. If i only transform the canvas, is this still possible then?

Comment: This may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197656/looking-for-an-explanation-of-post-pre-set-translate-in-matrix-object-and-how

Comment: What I have now is more complex then this example since it concatenates matrices from the parent objects, when I apply the matrix to the canvas instead of the bitmap it gets messed up, but I will continue trying

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to use a matrix to do transformation on lines in Android.

It's a little roundabout but hope it helps someone.

The following code is to rotate a line around it's center.

```
// coordinates of line (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)
float x1,y1,x2,y2; 

// get the center of the line
float centerX = Math.abs((x1+x2)/2);
float centerY = Math.abs(y1+y2)/2;

// set the angle
double angle = 90;

// put the lines in an array
float[] linePts = new float[] {x1, y1, x2, y2};

// create the matrix
Matrix rotateMat = new Matrix();

// rotate the matrix around the center              
rotateMat.setRotate((float) angle, centerX, centerY);
rotateMat.mapPoints(linePts);

// draw the line
mcanvas.drawLine(linePts [0], linePts [1], linePts [2], linePts [3], mPaint);
```

Hope this helps.